# Add links to certain keyword

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add internal links to certain keyword, like linking all the word `index` to the home page of my site.

I am planning to use BeautifulSoup4 but I don't know how to add tag to certain word inside an element.

This is what I want.

```
<div>You can find the content from the index page</div>
```

To

```
<div>You can find the content from the <a href='index.html'>index</a> page</div>
```

The challenging part here is simple `replace` might not work well here because what if the word `index` is already a link? then it will be totally screwd up into something like

```
<div>You can find the content from the <a href='index.html'><a href="index.html">index</a></a></div>
```

I prefer this to be implemented in Beautifulsoup with logics including:

1. Check if word is already inside a link or not
2. how to extract that specific word and add link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Below I go through all the `div` tags and see if there alread is a link to index.html, if there isn't I check if the word "index" is in them.  If it is, I create a new `div`, add the first part of the text, add a new `a` tag with the index.html link, and then add the rest of the text, otherwise it just passes through.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div>You can find content from the current index page.</div><div>You can find content from the <a href='index.html'>index</a> page.</div><div>Just random text</div>")
print(soup)
div_data = soup.find_all("div")
newsoup = BeautifulSoup("<h1></h1>")
i = 1
for item in div_data:
    if item.find("a", {"href":"index.html"}):
        newitem = item
    elif item.text.find("index") > -1:
        newitem = newsoup.new_tag("div")
        indexItem = newsoup.new_tag("a", href="index.html")
        indexItem.string="index"
        newitem.string = item.text.split("index")[0]
        newitem.insert(1,indexItem)
        newitem.insert(2,item.text.split("index")[1])
    else:
        newitem = item
    newsoup.body.insert(i,newitem)
    i += 1

print(newsoup)
```

The output is:

```
<html><body><div>You can find content from the current index page.</div>
<div>You can find content from the <a href="index.html">index</a> page.</div>
<div>Just random text</div></body></html>

<html><body><h1></h1><div>You can find content from the current <a href="index.html">index</a> page.</div>
<div>You can find content from the <a href="index.html">index</a> page.</div>
<div>Just random text</div></body></html>
```

You can imporve it by checking if there are multiple occurances of the word "index" but this will get you started.